# Why would an Echo command ever be written to a file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file

I encountered a scenario, where a `.bat` file, which had not changed over a very long time, was, instead of *printing `echo` to the command prompt*, creating a file called `0` in the current working directory, which contained the *string that was given as a parameter to `echo`*.

I am not able to replicate this behavior, which is why *I am wondering if someone knows what a **potential cause** of this could be*.

This was the case in *every command prompt window* until I restarted the machine. After that the **same file** printed the `echo` to the CMD again.
This was also not the case for every `.bat` file that was executed.

Comment: `echo somestring > filename.ext` writes output string to a file instead of console.

Comment: @Akina The command the file was using was `echo somestring`.

Comment: It's a legitimate question, but it's not worth wasting time investigating irreproducible weird behaviour that disappears after a reboot. That's Windows, it's a feature.